# Invalid memory alloc request size 1610613056 in Greenplum 4.3.14.0

Tags: greenplum

I have table "test" and I create it with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id bigint,
  str1 timestamp without time zone,
  str2 text,
  str3 text
);
```

After create table I added data:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '2017-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg1', 'sfgsdhgy1');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, '2016-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg2', 'sfgsdhgy2');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, '2015-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg3', 'sfgsdhgy3');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4, '2014-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg4', 'sfgsdhgy4');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (5, '2013-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg5', 'sfgsdhgy5');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (6, '2012-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg6', 'sfgsdhgy6');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (7, '2011-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg7', 'sfgsdhgy7');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (8, '2010-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg8', 'sfgsdhgy8');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (9, '2009-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg9', 'sfgsdhgy9');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (10, '2008-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg10', 'sfgsdhgy10');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (11, '2009-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg11', 'sfgsdhgy11');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (12, '2015-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg12', 'sfgsdhgy12');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (13, '2020-08-29 10:51:40.190913', 'gfsdfg13', 'sfgsdhgy13');
```

And then we I trying UPDATE this table with such query:

```
UPDATE test SET
    str1 = c.str1,
    str2 = c.str2,
    str3 = c.str3
FROM (
    VALUES
        (10, '2017-08-29 11:11:37'::timestamp without time zone, 'str2-10', 'str3-10'),
        (11, '2017-08-29 11:11:37'::timestamp without time zone, 'str2-11', 'str3-11'),
        (12, '2017-08-29 11:11:37'::timestamp without time zone, 'str2-12', 'str3-12'),
        (13, '2017-08-29 11:11:37'::timestamp without time zone, 'str2-13', 'str3-13')
) AS c (id, str1, str2, str3)
WHERE c.id = test.id;
```

And I got error:

> ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1610613056 (context 'ExecutorState') (mcxt.c:1069) (mcxt.c:477)  (seg0 node03:40000 pid=113577) (cdbdisp.c:1322)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

What version of GPDB are you using?

There are a few known planner errors -- this looks like an older legacy planner issue.

Can you try the same with `set optimizer=on;` or off?

With the large memory allocation size it's more likely this is an issue with statistics for the tables causing the planner to blow up.

As a best practice, follow up every `CREATE` with an `ANALYZE`.

`ANALYZE` the tables then running the query again.

Comment: I should add that I was not able to reproduce this with 4.3.12+

Comment: What version of GPDB are you using?

Sorry!
Version of GreenPlum: 
PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.3.14.0 build 1) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on May 25 2017 07:18:28
OS:
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

Using `set optimizer=on;` did not help me with my issue.

Comment: How can I print ALL(!) configuration for compare with different system?


When I ran these queries on different system (three lxd containers), everything ok (rows were updated by new data).
Versions of OS and Greenplum are identically.

Comment: In document below I saved configurations (result of query - SHOW ALL;) of my systems. But configurations are identically. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v01z1ZHlGxsYpmabba13lbnndxn8sWzauxMQ40XJXqQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I would recommend `ANALYZE test`, or `ANALYZE system` -- if there is only 13 rows then it's quite possible that something has incorrect stats causing the planner inflation.

Comment: Yes, there is only 13 rows in table "test" (I dropped this table, before created again). 
Also I analyzed (analyze <table_name>) other tables in this database on this server.
But these operations did not help me with this issue.
Maybe, there are some "hidden" settings are available for tuning database or alternative way to update statistics for tables/databases?)
Thanks for your assist!

Comment: What's your statement_mem set to?

Comment: Sorry for delay. My max_statement_mem is 2000MB and statement_mem is 125MB.